# Bootstrap navbar links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Have searched a bit and think I have missed something in how navbar links work.  I understand this style of link that works for something like a single page site and it indexes to the place on the page.

```
<a href="#about">About</a>
```

However, I am seeing lots of sites with links like this

```
<a href="about">About</a>
```

I am assuming that some type of language like Ruby, PHP or a framework is being used, but I have not stumbled on what is being used.  It looks like it is pretty common.  Are people just using mod_rewrite to remove extensions like .php in the url?  Anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: There are lot of frameworks out there which does this.. `AngularJS` is one of the example.. We cannot tell you exactly what is there unless you provide more details..

Comment: That example you have there goes to two different places. `<a href="#about">About</a>` will jump to an element with the `id="about"` attribute where as `<a href="about">About</a>` will go to about.html (may also be .php or something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is why is there no file extension in the link, such as href="about.php" or href="about.html"?

The answer is quite broad without specifics, I would say the majority of file extensions are removed using mod_rewrite/htaccess. As a basic example, WordPress will not display .html or .php extensions unless you create a custom permalink to do so.

Although I have not tested the examples on this site (credit: Alex Cican), I believe they should give you an indication as to how extensions are removed: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Of course there are other scenarios, such as the construction of URLs in frameworks like Django, but the above should satisfy your question.

Comment: After more research it looks that most frameworks are doing this.